# How many fours can be formed from eight sports teams?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have eight teams, let them be A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H. Two teams can form a pair, e.g. AB (BA is exactly the same pair). Then, pairs can make up into fours. For instance, AB, CD, EF and GH is an example of a four. Again, the order of pairs in the four does not matter.

The question is: how many different fours can be formed?

At school, we were solving problems like "In how many ways can you arrange 8 different objects (no identical ones)?" It's 8! = 40320. Here, however, you may arrange/combine them in any way you wish. In the described above situation with sports teams, you cannot use any letter more than once. E.g. **BC** and **CD** cannot coexist in the same four.

Basically, the answer is not that important for me; I just wonder which formula should I use or where I can read some information or maybe watch any Youtube videos about combinatorics problems where certain objects don't 'like' the other ones (combinations have restrictions).

Comment: Is *every* selection of $4$ distinct letters a "four" in this context? If so then there are $\binom84$. If not then what is the obstacle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply denote each pair of team a *match*

I think the answer is $105$. First, there are $ \binom {8}{2}$ ways to select the first *match*, then from the remaining $6$ teams, there are $ \binom {6}{2}$ ways to select the second *match* and similarly $ \binom {4}{2}$ ways to select the third *match*. Accordingly, the last match is determined.

But each way we draw the four matches is repeated $ 4! =24$ times, thus the answer is:

$ \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} :24 = 105$

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for the number of **fours**, not pairs.

So imagine that there are two *numbered* courts , you can send the players into the two courts in $\dfrac{8!}{4!4!} = 70$ ways

But since we aren't interested in which court number a player goes to, the required answer is $\dfrac{70}{2!} = 35$ ways

---

**Answer modified according to OP's clarification**

OP has clarified that by "fours" is meant four pairs including all $8$ teams.

Then, by the same logic of first imagining $4$ courts, division can be into $\dfrac{8!}{2!2!2!2!} \div4! = 105$ fours

Comment: I meant fours which are made of pairs. Pairs are grouped together, and four of them make a 'four' (a four-pair set, if you want). Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Again confused. **Two** distinct pairs put together should make a **four,** which is what gives $35$ as the answer.

Comment: My four consists of all eight teams. But, on the other hand, it consists of four pairs (4*2 = 8). So basically all eight teams participate in the four.

Comment: Ok, so you essentially want all $8$ teams grouped into pairs. I'll  expand the last part of my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are $7$ possible choices for $A$'s partner. Now let $X$ be the next unpaired player (i.e. $X$ is $B$ unless $B$ was paired with $A$, in which case $X$ is $C$). There are $5$ choices for $X$'s partner. Now let $Y$ be the next unpaired player. There are $3$ choices for $Y$'s partner.

So the answer is $7\times 5\times 3=105$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom 84$ ways to choose the $4$ teams that make up your four.  Once you've selected $4$ teams, there are $3$ distinct ways to pair them up within the four.  Thus, the answer is $210=3 \times \binom 84$.

Comment: is this the correct answer?

Comment: I think this is based on a misinterpretation of the question. In the OP's terminology, a _four_ contains all eight teams. (It is striking that including all eight teams causes a _reduction_ in the number of possibilities, from $210$ to $105$.)